# iPhone iOS is there an expression parser for an algebraic calculator-like app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, parsing, expression

I'm building an app that would analyze phone's motion through accelerometer and gyroscope output. It is likely that I will capture this motion as a set of variables that the app would keep track of internally.

I'm trying to include a way to graph these variables and equations involving these variables. I would like to offer the user an ability to adjust how the app displays equations of these variables by typing equations like a + b - c = d  with the a,b,c variables being calculated by my app. The user can write equations and graph variables in the field. Since it has been ages since I wrote an algebraic parser in any language, **I'm wandering if there's an expression parser in objective-c that I can readily plug into my app**, where a user would type something like a + b - c = d into a text field and the app would tokenize and substitute variables that I provide in place of the user-entered placeholders.

Comment: I'd bet anything you can find something in C and adapt it pretty easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of open source options:

GCMathParser 
http://www.apptree.net/parser.htm

DDMathParser
https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser

Comment: The DDMathParser is really very simple to use.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much easier approach to do this :) Check out the NSExpression foundation class. It is the same class used when you type an expression into the spotlight.

[NSExpression Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSExpression/expressionWithFormat:argumentArray:)

In Objective-C

```
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"2*4*3" argumentArray:nil];
NSNumber *result = [expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
```

In Swift

```
var expression:NSExpression = NSExpression(format: "4 + (3 * 2)", argumentArray: [])
var result = expression.expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: nil)
```