# Convert NSString with factor (e.g. @"3/4") to NSNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to convert a string for example

```
NSString *stringWithNumber = @"3/4"
```

into a `NSNumber`.
How is this possible?

Comment: what do you want to convert it to? `3`? `4`? `0.75`?

Comment: What you want is an expression interpreter/evaluator.  I don't know of any "standard" one on iOS, but I think there are a few open source ones floating around.

Comment: For `@"3.0/4.0"` you could use `NSExpression`, as shown for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12500518/1187415. But for your input that would do a integer division and produce zero. - See also [What is a fast C or Objective-C math parser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892152/what-is-a-fast-c-or-objective-c-math-parser).

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064103/iphone-ios-is-there-an-expression-parser-for-an-algebraic-calculator-like-app

Comment: @HotLicks correct. There are some around, but if the use case is restricted to fractions, it may be too much of an effort ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an `NSEXpression` to "calculate" the value. Note that you will have the regular int division problem with "3/4".

```
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"3.0/4.0"];
NSNumber *result = [expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
```

Comment: sleek, even though is the input string is `3/4`, as you already noted, it won't work as expected.

Comment: I have solved `int` problem in this case. See this - [Convert to Float and Calculate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155360/convert-to-float-and-calculate/14155699#14155699)

Answer (score 4):

If you are only working with `n/m` fractions, and you mean to have a number representing the result of the fraction, you can do something like

```
NSString *fraction = @"3/4";
NSArray *components = [fraction componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
float numerator = [components[0] floatValue];
float denominator = [components[1] floatValue];
NSNumber *result = @(numerator/denominator);
NSLog(@"%@", result); // => 0.75
```

Of course this can easily break in case of malformed strings, so you may want to check the format before performing the above computation.

**NOTE**

In case the fractions coming in input have a format compatible with native float division, David's answer is definitely sleeker and less clunky than mine. Although if you have an input like `@"3/4"`, it won't work as expected and you definitely need to do something like I suggested above.

Bottom line, you should specify better your requirements.

Comment: Your answer will work in case of 3/4, 5/6 .... n/m only. What if string be in other formats ?

Comment: Quoting my own answer. *Of course this can easily break in case of malformed strings, so you may want to check the format before performing the above computation.* Without further information from the OP, there's no much more I can say. I frankly don't think my answer deserves a downvote, since it addresses the question as exposed  by the OP.

Comment: The Question is **I want to convert a string into NSNumber for example ____** and for example means this is just an example.

Comment: Again, without requirements you can't really say anything more. I cannot read minds and neither can you. What makes you think that he needs more than `n/m` fractions? This is a reasonable answer to a poorly formulated question

Comment: Oh dude I didn't want to down vote It happen by mistake and now I cant get it back until you make an edit ... And of course answer is specific. I think answer should be for all **string to number**. Programmer would not like to make different code for every different formula string. Hope you are getting !!

Comment: I get it, but programmers should't shoot with a bazooka to a fly either. If you have a very specific problem, a super-generic answer may not be the best one. Again, lack of clear requirements is the biggest issue here.